# Are global CSS helper classes a good idea?

Tags: html, css, architecture

Say I have a color I know I am going to use a lot of in a website.

I could either define the colour lots of times in various CSS class's

```
.nav-login { color:#green; other CSS content....... }
```

Or

```
.green {color:green;}
.nav-login { other CSS content....... }

<div class="nav-login green">stuff</div>
```

So the concept is, should you use helper CSS classes or should you define everything specific?

Theoretically, you will save bandwidth in the long term by writing more CSS and less HTML, yet I find the method of applying helper CSS classes in the HTML pleasing, almost as if you are writing semantic CSS in a design sense.

Comment: You should give [less](http://lesscss.org/) a try.

Comment: If you're only going to recommend 1 *CSS preprocessor*, at least recommend a good one.  LESS is *less* than Sass in pretty much every way.

Comment: @cimmanon That's the point of LESS, like in the [KISS principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle). Don't use 5% of a complex system when all you need is a simple preprocessor which allows for nesting rules and some simple macros allowing for DRY. I don't need SASS, I don't want to force my non-developers colleagues to use that. LESS is as good as another preprocessor *depending on your requirements*. YMMV (and it's OT here)

Comment: As far as I can see, this question has a clear answer. Use a CSS preprocessor langauge, to allow you to use variables across your CSS.

Answer (score 3):

I personally don't think it's a good idea to name classes based on their properties, like `.green` for a green-colored text. Instead, use a qualifier, say `.approved` for green text, and `.warning` for warnings, alerts and etc.

In my humble opinion, the selectors (classes, IDs) should reflect the role/purpose of the element, and not their appearance. Say for example, if you want to redesign your site and adopt a new colour scheme, and your navigation menu changes from green to blue - then, the `.green` selector will have very little meaning, and will be hard to understand to whoever is taking over the project in the future, if any.

Moreover, there is no reason to assign a `.green` class to the navigation login `<div>`, if you can already specify it using `.nav-login`.

Chris Coyier has compiled a rather comprehensive [CSS style guide](http://css-tricks.com/css-style-guides/) - it's not the golden rule, but it's good to follow.

Comment: Ah, it wouldn't have to be green. It could be master_leading_brand_colour for example. Ah, now I get less + sass. If I can define variables in my CSS, then I can just make the colour change via a variable. Cool.

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at [OOCSS](http://oocss.org/) (and [Smashing Mag introduction to it](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/12/12/an-introduction-to-object-oriented-css-oocss/))) if you didn't already have. Also to [BEM](http://bem.info/method/) from Yandex - again [Smashing Mag intro to it](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2012/04/16/a-new-front-end-methodology-bem/).

I'd have laughed at the idea of not strictly separating content (HTML) from style (CSS) a few years ago, I scratched my head when Nicole "stubbornella" Sullivan gave a talk about it in a conference I attended but now that I'm working on projects made of dozens of pages to where we have to go from PSD to HTML/CSS for a client inside a team of a few people, my requirements have drastically changed! 
Working alone on CSS that nobody else will modify *or* in a team on a single project in a startup *or* in a team for a client that'll reuse the CSS you create aren't the same at all.

Learn about OOCSS and what it can do for you, give it a try and don't use it in your projects if it isn't suitable. Or do.

Using CSS preprocessors or not is quite irrelevant here: if you use them to output 1 kilometer long selectors, you're using them wrong obviously. They're just a way to write CSS faster and with less pain (not having to bother to learn which prefix are needed for each CSS3 property thanks to macros is great, but they should still output more or less the same CSS than before). The point is to write efficient CSS, with or without a preprocessor. Same with ZenCoding/Emmet: you know you need it when you're fed up with writing the same repeated lines/instructions day after day. But they'll output these same lines of CSS, nothing magical here.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, it is a good idea. I use them too, but I do not name them the way you said. teddyrised' example is good.

Just my example, when I make a simple project that does not need a huge page structure and minimal CSS, I name them like this:

```css
.push-right {
    float: right;
}

push-left {
    float: left;
}

.no-float {
    float: none;
}

.centered {
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.success {
    color: green;
}

.error {
    color: red;
}

.warning {
    color: orange;
}

.info {
    color: blue;
}
```

So actually it is okay to use them. Just watch out for naming them :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to offer a completely different solution to your problem. Use [Less](http://lesscss.org/).

Using this, you will be able to define variables and a lot of other cool stuff too.

> Variables allow you to specify widely used values in a single place, and then re-use them throughout the style sheet, making global changes as easy as changing one line of code.